# Google Analytics 4 conversions don't show up in Google Ads account

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, google-analytics-4

I started a Google Analytics account from my personal account and I started Google Ads from my company account.

I set up GA4 events in my website and marked them as conversions in Google Analytics. My ads account is linked to my analytics account. It has all the necessary permissions and my conversions get imported into my ads account.

However after initially some conversions showed up as counted in my ads account (1 of approx. 15 events has a count of 5 while this event has several hundred on ads the others still have zero) by now nothing gets counted in ads at all. One event shows that conversions are supposedly recorded the others also show that nothing has been recorded lately.

I tried a lot. Delinked everything. Played around with all kinds of property and account permissions but nothing seems to have worked.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the campaign does not seem to be recognized as first interaction by Google Analytics. Could that have something to do with the error?